# Chi-Square Value too small for df = 6, am I using the wrong number of df?

Tags: probability, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I'm not very good at statistics so I figured I could ask here to see if anyone could help me.
I need to do a goodness of fit test for a table of 7 data points:

| Energy | Observed Flux | Expected Flux |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 2.04e-12 | 2.47e-12 |
| 0.44 | 1.64e-12 | 2.15e-12 |
| 0.65 | 1.16e-12 | 1.01e-12 |
| 0.96 | 8.09e-13 | 6.85e-13 |
| 1.4 | 6.07e-13 | 3.83e-13 |
| 2.06 | 5e-13 | 3.64e-13 |
| 3.03 | 3.99e-13 | 6.02e-13 |

Because the values are so small I use a small variation of the Chi-Squared Formula:
$$\chi^2 = \frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i c_s}$$
Where $c_s$ is the smallest value of the data.
Because I have 7 data points, I use df = 6 but when doing the calculation mi Chi-Squared values is $\chi^2 = 0.03$ and the smallest value at .99 for 6 degrees of freedom is of 0.872, what should I do in this case? Are my df wrong?

Comment: The usual chisquared test is for count data, but you do not seem to have count data! Could you tell us which null hypothesis you want to test?

Comment: I don't think I have a null hypothesis, I just want to know if the observed values I calculated are a good fit to the expected values, should I have a null hypothesis then?

Comment: Empirically, it has a higher prediction for flux with small energy than for large energy as do the observations, so it is better than guessing flux is unaffected by energy.  But there is a  curious increase in the final expected flux, and another model could be much closer, for example $\mathrm{flux} \approx 8.4\times 10^{-13} \times \mathrm{energy}^{-0.734}$ found by linear regression on the logarithms of the the observations of energy and flux.